# shared_from_this() crashes in specific case

Tags: c++, this, shared-ptr

Option 1 crashes the app on `shared_from_this()` with bad_weak_ptr, while option 2 works fine, why? the only difference i see is where the clone is being created - in the `Clone()` function or in line with creating `shared_ptr` for the clone, in both cases the `shared_from_this` requirement of already having `shared_ptr` with ownership of `this` when using `shared_from_this()` is met

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* Clone() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>
{
public:
    Base* Clone() override
    {
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
    void test()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr = shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> obj = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    //std::shared_ptr<Base> clone = std::shared_ptr<Base>(obj->Clone()); // option 1
    std::shared_ptr<Base> clone = std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived(*std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(obj))); // option 2
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(clone);
    derived->test();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::make_shared<Derived>(...)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `new` an object that derives from `enable_shared_from_this`  and for it to safely work since the `new` object doesn't actually have a shared_ptr container.

Instead of this:

```
Base* Clone() override
{
    return new Derived(*this);
}
```

This:

```
shared_ptr<Base> Clone() override
{
    return make_shared<Derived>(*this);
}
```

Similar adjustment in the base class declaration:

```
virtual shared_ptr<Base> Clone() = 0;
```

Comment: Is it the only way? it's not necessary for me to keep the raw pointer return value for cloning function, but i would like to keep it if possible

Comment: The problem is not that `new Derived` should not be used, but that to make `shared_from_this()` work, then the first time when the new object is stored in a `shared_ptr`, that has to be a `shared_ptr<Derived>`, not a `shared_ptr<Base>`.